# Linq issue, Unable to get expected data C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Student>` object with data like below

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SchoolYearId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
}
```

& Data I have this

```
    public List<Student> StudentData()
    {
       return new List<Student>
       {
         new Student
         {
             StudentId=100,
             Name="Shubham",
             SchoolYearId=2016,
              ClassId=1000
         },
         new Student
         {
          StudentId=100,
          Name="Shubham",
          SchoolYearId=2017,
          ClassId=1001    
         },
         new Student
         {
          StudentId=100,
          Name="Shubham",
          SchoolYearId=2018,
          ClassId=1002
          },

         new Student
         {
           StudentId=101,
           Name="Arpit",
           SchoolYearId=2016,
           ClassId=1100
         },
        new Student
        {
          StudentId=101,
          Name="Arpit",
          SchoolYearId=2017,
         ClassId=1101
         }

       };
     }
```

Now my requirement is,I need Students Distinct by `StudentId` Where `SchoolYearId` is Max for each student.

So result I am expecting

```
   StudentId=100,
   Name="Shubham",
   SchoolYearId=2018,
   ClassId=1002                      

   StudentId=101,
   Name="Arpit",
   SchoolYearId=2017,
   ClassId=1101
```

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Please read the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post a more complete question.

Comment: I have tried `MaxBy` SchoolYearId & `GroupBy` StudentId than Select But not able to get it

Comment: I assume you are using MoreLinq? If so, `GroupBy` **then** `MaxBy`. http://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2_1.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *group by* (`GroupBy`) first, and compute *argmax* within each group second; alas, *Linq* doesn't have any `ArgMax`, but it can be easily emulated via `Aggregate`

```
var result = StudentData()
  .GroupBy(student => student.StudentId)
  .Select(group => group
     .Aggregate((s, a) => s.SchoolYearId > a.SchoolYearId ? s : a))
  .ToList(); // Let's materialize into list
```

Comment: Beautiful idea using `Aggregate` for `ArgMax`... Hadn't ever thought.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
var data = StudentData()
               .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
               .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.SchoolYearId).First());
```

You `GroupBy` the `StudentId`, then for each group you `OrderByDescending` by `SchoolYearId`, so that the element with the maximum value is the first one, then you take the `First`.